# JPQL: How to include Forward Slash in Query String?

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, jpql

How do you properly escape a '/' forward slash in a JPQL query string?

If I do this:

```
LOCATE('/', REVERSE( ...
```

I get:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
```

However, if I do this:

```
LOCATE('\\', REVERSE( ...
```

Everything is fine.

So, how do I include the forward slash?

EDIT: I've already tried the following and they don't work:

```
'\\/'
'//'
CHAR(47)
ESCAPE '/'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't reproduce with the provided details, the following works for me:

```
@Test
public void testQueryWithLocateKeyword() {
    Product p1 = new Product("1234/Foo");
    Product p2 = new Product("12/Bar");
    em.persist(p1);
    em.persist(p2);
    em.flush();

    String qlString = "SELECT LOCATE('/', p.name) FROM Product p";

    List actual = em.createQuery(qlString).getResultList();

    List<Integer> expected = Arrays.asList(5, 3);

    assertNotNull(actual);
    ReflectionAssert.assertReflectionEquals(expected, actual);
}
```

Tested with Hibernate EM 3.5 (and H2).

Please provide a representative query, a full stacktrace, the Hibernate version.

Comment: Yep, your right ... it was due to a different error. Sorry for the inconvenience, but thanks for the help anyway.